# Is it possible to change size of a class member buffer

Tags: c++, spi

I have a SPI test class which I am trying to make flexible specially for user to be able to change\set the size of the Tx and Rx buffers which are private members of SpiTest class.
I have tried few ways by `const_cast` etc., but compiler keeps giving different sort of errors each time.
What would be best way to make my `SpiTest` class flexible enough to provide user a function which can be used to change the size of the buffer or may be just set a size of the buffer once but by client/user. Even once after creating test object to initialize size will be good enough.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.
I have tried

1. Using Tx_size member as static then it complains about constness
   1b- making Tx_size const complains about setting size is not possible using SetTxSize() method.
2. Initialising it in constructor not advantage.
3. Applying const_cast but that is only applicable to change pointer types consts
4. This is my class:

   ```
   class SPITest
   {
     public:
     SPITest();
     ~SPITest() = default;

     uint8_t* GetTxBuf(void)
     {
       return &TX_m[0];
     }

     uint8_t* GetRxBuf(void)
     {
       return &RX_m[0];
     }

     uint8_t GetTxSize(void)
     {
       return Tx_Size;    
     }

     void SetTxSize(uint8_t size)
     {
       Tx_Size=  (size);       
    }

    private:
      static uint8_t Tx_Size = 6;
      uint8_t TX_m[Tx_Size]; 
      uint8_t RX_m[Tx_Size]; 
   };
   ```

Errors are as follows:

> Error[Pe1592]: a member with an in-class initializer must be const
>   Error[Pe028]: expression must have a constant value

Comment: use a `std::vector` if you need dynamic size

Comment: Use `std::vector<uint8_t>` for `TX_m` and `RX_m`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ for once I was faster than you :P

Comment: @formerly That's easy to happen, I am an old man ;-)

Comment: Alternatively: `template <size_t BufferSize> class SPITest { std::array<uint8_t, BufferSize> buffer; };` – you'd specify size when defining the object, you couldn't change during runtime, though.

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks for your input. That sounds to be a good solution as only need to set size once initial set up time. This looks like solution with less overhead too. Thanks again.

Comment: *'less overhead'*: in general, yes (you spare one level of indirection). Solely *moving* is more expensive, `std::array` embeds the array directly, so it must be copied even on moving. Suppose that usually shouldn't be an issue in the scenario you describe, but you might keep in mind for other ones...

Comment: @Aconcagua, you can do something like below to have variable size at runtime, `class A { public: A(size_t size) { tx = new int[size]}  private: int *tx; .... }`

Comment: @VasanthAlagiriswamy Well, one *could*. But for dynamic sizes at run-time, there's already a far better approach proposed: `std::vector`...

Comment: @VasanthAlagiriswamy Additionally: Better get used to constructors initializer list: `A(size_t size) : tx(new int[size]) { }` – you avoid default initialisation + assignment in favour of direct initialisation by value; some types (non-default-constructible ones and references) *only* can be initialised this way.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a vector

Use a `std::vector` instead - a vector is a dynamic array.

Your class then becomes:

```
#include <vector>

class SPITest
{
public:
    //...
    void SetTxSize(size_t size)
    {
        TX_m.resize(size);
    }

private:
    std::vector<uint8_t> TX_m; 
    std::vector<uint8_t> RX_m; 
};
```

Comment: better remove `static`, and the setters should resize the vector, either way better make it consistent

Comment: @darune thanks for your input , it is indeed helpful.
resize method and std::vector generally bring a lot of overhead ,using template solution seems probably with less overhead?

Comment: What sort of "overhead" are you imagining there, @A786?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In c++ vectors specially when resized they double the size rather than adding or expanding to that size only. That generally is more memory unsuitable in case of larger buffer sizes. That is my understanding based on few practical examples analyses.

Comment: @A786 [No, they don't](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f307e03ef90c7a5b). You're thinking of what happens when you push_back or emplace_back.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  thank you for pointing out i will double check and update.

Comment: @A786 Main difference in run-time: `std::array` embeds the array directly, `std::vector` uses a pointer to externally located array. So when accessing the array, `std::vector` requires one additional dereferencing operation. But unless running in *extreme* high performance scenario, you most likely won't ever notice this difference... Of course, if a user changes size during run-time to a greater one than current capacity, a new array needs to be allocated – which *will* cost. But that's an operation not even available for `std::array`...

Comment: @A786  So main concern for your decision `std::vector` vs. `std::array` should be: Is it *meaningful* to allow users to change buffer size or not?